# Laravel routing in subdirectories

Tags: php, laravel-4

Lets say that I have a folder structure that strays away from the default:

```
app/controllers
app/models
app/views
```

but what if I wanted something like this:

```
app/Site/Admin/controllers
app/Site/Admin/models
app/Site/Admin/views
---------------------
app/Site/Public/controllers
app/Site/Public/models
app/Site/Public/views
```

I thought namespacing a controller would be used? e.g.

```
namespace App/Site/Admin/controllers;
```

use App\Controllers\BaseController;

```
class DashboardController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        echo "hey";
    }

}
```

and then routing

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'App\Site\Admin\controllers\DashboardController@index');
});
```

I've been testing but i can't quite get it working.

Comment: What exactly not working? What error do you get?

Comment: production.ERROR: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Site\Admin\controllers\DashboardController does not exist' in C:\xampp\htdocs\structure\bootstrap\compiled.php:242

Comment: Did you configured psr-4 autoloading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.first thing you need to do is register the new folder you added to composer autoload.
2.second i say your namespace definition is wrong .

based on your structure,you shoud add this line in you composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
              "": ["app/Site/Admin","app/Site/Public"]
         }
}
```

this will autoload all the file in app/site/Admin and app/Site/Public when you use them

then from your command line,go to root folder of your project :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

this command will regenerate composer autoload file

And your namespace should be :

```
namespace App\Site\Admin\controllers;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your composer.json file, you need to configure the classmap property as such:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/Site/Admin/commands",
        "app/Site/Admin/controllers",
        "app/Site/Admin/models",
        "app/Site/Admin/database/migrations",
        "app/Site/Admin/database/seeds",
        "app/Site/Admin/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
```

Then do `composer update` to load the new classmap.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would choose creating sub directories within the main /app folders. This way I'll have a second application, but still be able to reuse functionalities and manage it easier. So the file structure would look something like:

```
/app
--/controllers
----SomeController.php

----/Admin/DashboardController.php
-------DashboardController.php
```

Which Laravel version are you using? You can check this with:

```
php artisan --version
```

If you are using 4.2.*, you could simply add namespace to your route group, like so:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'), function(){
    Route::resource('dashboard', 'DashboardController');
}
```

Don't forget to also update your composer.json with the sub directories like @lowerends suggested and then execute the autoloading:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/controllers/Admin",
        "app/models/Admin",
        ...
    ]
},

# from the cli
composer dump-autoload
```

And finally, don't forget to add the according namespace to your classes, like so:

```
<?php
namespace Admin;

class DashboardController extends BaseController {
    ...

    # if for some reason you are referring to say a model class within the global namespace prefix it with a ("\") back slash

    // /app/models/User.php
    $users = \User::all();

    // /app/models/Admin/User.php
    $users = User::all()

}
```